# FileUtils write method does not work on Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, scala, databricks, azure-databricks, fileutils

I have troubles writing a file on my Databricks cluster's driver (as a temp file). I have a scala notebook on my company's Azure Databricks which contains those lines of code :

```scala
val xml: String = Controller.requestTo(url)
val bytes: Array[Byte] = xml.getBytes

val path: String = "dbfs:/data.xml"
val file: File = new File(path)
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, bytes)

dbutils.fs.ls("dbfs:/")

val df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
                   .option("rowTag", "generic:Obs")
                   .load(path)

df.show

file.delete()
```

however it crashes with `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: dbfs:/data.xml`. When I run a `ls` on the root of the dbfs, it doesn't show the file `data.xml` so for me FileUtils is not doing it's job. What puts me even more in troubles is that the following code works when running it on the same cluster, same Azure resource group, same instance of Databricks, but in another notebook :

```
val path: String = "mf-data.grib"
val file: File = new File(path)
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, bytes)
```

I tried to restart the cluster, remove "dbfs:/" from the path, put the file in the `dbfs:/tmp/` directory, use `FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, xml, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` instead of `FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile` but none of those solutions has worked, even when combining them.

Comment: Also tried `Files.write(Paths.get("dbfs:/data.xml"), xml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))` without success. It causes the same exception. Thus, it might be a deeper issue than just FileUtils.writeStringToFile and Files.write not working

Comment: Hope this has been taken care on location stand . https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#summary-table-and-diagram

Answer (score 2):

If you're using local APIs, like, `File`, you need to use corresponding [local file access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/databricks-file-system#local-file-apis) - instead of using `dbfs:/` you need to prefix path with `/dbfs/`, so your code will look as following:

```
val file: File = new File(path.replaceFirst("dbfs:", "/dbfs")
```

Comment: Ok that's quite strange because I didn't do it on another notebook and it worked fine, but not here haha. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the `dbfs` here : `val path: String = "dbfs:/data.xml"` for understanding purposes I have given 3 different magical command cells `%sh , %fs, %scala` . You can ref : [here](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#summary-table-and-diagram)

[image]

Comment: Tried it but it still fails. I tried using dbutils put function but it works randomly (sometimes it works, sometimes it fails)